# How to edit read() system call in linux?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, system, system-calls

I have a final assignment for a CS class to edit the read() system call in Ubuntu 16.04 so that every time it reads a file, it changes lowercase e to uppercase E. I know I need to use a loadable kernel module, but I don't really understand how I can edit the system call to achieve this.

Comment: Did you look into the kernel's source code? Did you find how and where `read` system call is implemented? Do you know about [FUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I'm not sure, this is my first time dealing with kernels and LKMs. I know I need to use a LKM to change the system call but I'm not sure how I would go about implementing it. Also for the assignment, I need to actually modify the system call in the kernel, so I can't use FUSE.

Comment: You probably want to work only inside a particular file system. Because changing *every* `e` will corrupt your system badly (since most binary files, including executables, are big enough to contain it).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Yes, what I mean is - when read() is called to read a file, it changes the text in that particular file.

Comment: So you also need to do something for `open`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have no idea... my professor didn't say anything regarding the open() call, so I assume there is a way to modify read() to do this without modifying anything else.

Comment: You need to read more, notably about [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode)s and [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor)s. I strongly recommend quickly reading the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf) before coding anything kernel related.

Comment: to me it seems more likely that you should be using ptrace(),  if you start messing with the file subsystem nothing will run.